# How to call the same function with different datatype?

Tags: c++, types, arguments

Here is a class which can be called with different datatype:

```
template<class TDataType> 
void SetProperties(IndexType PropertiesId, 
                   const Variable<TDataType>& rVariable, 
                   const TDataType& Value)
{
    mpModeler->SetProperties(PropertiesId, rVariable, Value);
}
```

where Modeler::SetProperties is defined as:

```
template<class TDataType> 
void SetProperties(IndexType PropertiesId, 
                   const Variable<TDataType>& rVariable, 
                   const TDataType& Value)
{
    if (mpModel->GetProperties(PropertiesId).get() == 0)
    {
        mpModel->AddProperties(PropertiesId, Properties::Pointer(new Properties(*mpModel)));
    }

    PropertyFunction<TDataType>::Pointer constant_property(new ConstantProperty<TDataType>(Value));

    mpModel->GetProperties(PropertiesId)->SetProperty(rVariable, constant_property);
}
```

The class `SetProperties` is called by:

```
yyvsp[0].statement_handler->Execute(mpKernel);
```

Where `Execute()` is defined by:

```
template<class TDataType> class GeneratePropertiesStatement : public Statement
{
public:

    GeneratePropertiesStatement(int Id, 
                                const Kratos::Variable<TDataType>& rVariable, 
                                const TDataType& Value) : mId(Id), 
                                                         mVariable(rVariable), 
                                                         mValue(Value){}

    void Execute(Kratos::Kernel* pKernel)
    {
        pKernel->SetProperties(mId, mVariable, mValue);
    }

    int mId;
    Kratos::Variable<TDataType> mVariable;
    TDataType mValue;
};
```

Single data or multiple data are passed to Value by the following statements:

single data:

```
yyval.statement_handler = new GeneratePropertiesStatement<double>(yyvsp[-4].integer_value, *yyvsp[-2].double_variable, yyvsp[0].double_value);
```

where `yyvsp[0].double_value` is defined as `double`;

multiple data:

```
yyval.statement_handler = new GeneratePropertiesStatement<Kratos::Vector<double> >(yyvsp[-4].integer_value, *yyvsp[-2].vector_double_variable, *yyvsp[0].vector_double_value);
```

where `*yyvsp[0].vector_double_value` is defined as a `vector`.

However, the above realization rely on some external data and I need to call the function SetProperties directly. I defined the following argument and successfully called the function:

```
int i;
const Kratos::Variable<double>* double_variable;
double regionmapi;
...
pKernel->SetProperties(i, *double_variable, regionmapi);
```

However, when I defined the following argument and called the function to pass multiple data, it failed:

```
double tmp3[3];
std::vector<double>aa;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)aa.push_back(tmp3[i]);
pKernel->SetProperties(i, *double_variable, aa);
```

Could anyone help me to take a look at it?

Comment: Types are important in C++. If you need to call it with different types you have  two choices: 1. pass variable with type that is derived from expected type 2. Create new method that will convert passed type to expected type and call the orignal method

Comment: Can you post the error that you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call to `SetProperties` using multiple data, the second argument must be of type `Kratos::Variable<std::vector<double>>`, in order to be consistent with the third argument, which is of type `std::vector<double>`.  From the code you show, it looks like the second argument is of type `Kratos:Variable<double>`, which conflicts with the third argument.

Comment: thanks for your kindly reply. But the original code is OK, both single data (`yyvsp[0].double_value`) and multiple data (`*yyvsp[0].vector_double_value`)can be passed.